# Copy one matrix into another in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

How can I copy one matrix into another without for loops ? is it 
even possible ?

This is a short code that does it with loops , how can I avoid loops here ?

```
% middleImg , newImg are matrices 
[rows columns] = size(middleImg);
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:columns     
        newImg(i,j) = middleImg(i+1,j+1);
    end
end
```

Comment: Your loop will throw an error, since `middleImg` only has `rows` number of rows, but you're trying to read a value from row # `rows+1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just do:

```
  newImg = middleImg;
```

If what you meant is to copy everything but the first row and col, then just:

```
 newImg = middleImg(2:end,2:end);
```